# extracting text information from a national id

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, tesseract

I'm trying to do OCR arabic on the following ID but I get a very noisy picture, and can't extract information from it.

Here is my attempt

```
import tesserocr
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import matplotlib as plt
import cv2
import imutils
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread(r'c:\ahmed\ahmed.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray,11,18,18)

gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5), 0)

kernel = np.ones((2,2), np.uint8)


gray = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
#img_dilation = cv2.erode(gray, kernel, iterations=1)


#cv2.imshow("dilation", img_dilation)

cv2.imshow("gray", gray)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(gray, lang='ara')
print(text)
with open(r"c:\ahmed\file.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as myfile:
    myfile.write(text)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qrDQ.png)

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVXjv.jpg)

Comment: are you only interested in the text that is in the red box?

Answer (score 2):

The text for your id is in black color which makes the extraction process easy. All you need to do is threshold the dark pixels and you should be able to get the text out.

Here is a snip of the code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image in grayscale
image = cv2.imread('AVXjv.jpg',0)

# remove noise
dst = cv2.blur(image,(3,3))

# extract dark regions which corresponds to text
val, dst = cv2.threshold(dst,80,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# morphological close to connect seperated blobs
dst = cv2.dilate(dst,None)
dst = cv2.erode(dst,None)

cv2.imshow("dst",dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: There is a green text up which is not there in the thresholded picture

Comment: You can try processing the different channels separately to extract the green text.

Comment: @Qidi Can you post an answer with your approach ?

Comment: Why would you need the green text? Isn't it the same for all the ids?

Answer (score 0):

This is my output using ImageMagick TextCleaner script:

[image: out]

Script: `textcleaner -g -e stretch -f 50 -o 30 -s 1 C:/Users/PC/Desktop/id.jpg C:/Users/PC/Desktop/out.png`

Take a look [here](http://cvisiondemy.com/install-imagemagick-textcleaner-script-on-windows/) if you want to install and use TextCleaner script on Windows... It's a tutorial I made as simple as possible after few researches I made when I was in your same situation.

Now it should be very easy to detect the text and (not sure how simple) recognize it.